# Katalon Debian Headless Browser

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins, groovy, katalon-studio

I'm switching from Selenium to Katalon and i faced some problems.
I'm using Jenkins which is installed on Debian OS: 
I'm running this command:

```
./katalon --args -runMode=console -projectPath="/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/katalon_test/workspace/spot-systemtest/src/katalon/spot/katalon test.prj" \
-reportFolder="Reports" -reportFileName="report" \
-retry=0 -testSuitePath="Test Suites/WarmUp" \
-browserType="Headless"
```

and I'm getting exception during execution:

```
10-05-2017 06:41:34 AM - [ERROR] - Test Cases/core/login spot2 FAILED because (of) java.awt.HeadlessException: 
No X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but this program performed an operation which requires it.
```

When i'm setting variable to ":0" it complains:

```
10-05-2017 06:24:49 AM - [ERROR] - Test Cases/core/login spot2 FAILED because (of) java.awt.AWTError: Can't connect to X11 window server using ':0' as the value of the DISPLAY variable.
```

There is no XServer, because this is server OS.

I tired to add env. variable:
export JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.awt.headless=true"

also i tried to pass this parameter in katalon execution. 
Unfortunately nothing helped.

Second thing.
I'm getting errors on every step like this
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.internal.WebUIAbstractKeyword

the full stack trace is here

```
+ ./katalon --args -runMode=console -projectPath=/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/katalon_test/workspace/spot-systemtest/src/katalon/spot/katalon test.prj -reportFolder=Reports -reportFileName=report -retry=0 -testSuitePath=Test Suites/WarmUp -Djava.awt.headless=true -browserType=Headless
Starting Groovy-Eclipse compiler resolver.  Specified compiler level: unspecified
122 2.4.7.xx-201611170128-e46 = ACTIVE

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Test Suites/WarmUp - Headless - 20171005_062446..........................0/8(0%)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

10-05-2017 06:24:48 AM - [START]  - Start Test Suite : WarmUp
10-05-2017 06:24:48 AM - [RUN_DATA] - Logging run data 'hostName' with value 'root - ee4afc86e8bd'
10-05-2017 06:24:48 AM - [RUN_DATA] - Logging run data 'os' with value 'Linux 64bit'
10-05-2017 06:24:48 AM - [RUN_DATA] - Logging run data 'hostAddress' with value '172.17.0.8'
10-05-2017 06:24:48 AM - [RUN_DATA] - Logging run data 'katalonVersion' with value '4.8.0.2'
10-05-2017 06:24:48 AM - [START]  - Start Test Case : Test Cases/core/login spot2
10-05-2017 06:24:48 AM - [INFO]   - Evaluating variables for test case
10-05-2017 06:24:48 AM - [START]  - Start action : openBrowser
10-05-2017 06:24:49 AM - [END]    - End action : openBrowser
10-05-2017 06:24:49 AM - [ERROR]  - Test Cases/core/login spot2 FAILED because (of) java.awt.AWTError: Can't connect to X11 window server using ':0' as the value of the DISPLAY variable.
10-05-2017 06:24:49 AM - [END]    - End Test Case : Test Cases/core/login spot2
10-05-2017 06:24:49 AM - [START]  - Start Test Case : Test Cases/core/open_module_DASHBOARD
10-05-2017 06:24:49 AM - [INFO]   - Evaluating variables for test case
10-05-2017 06:24:49 AM - [START]  - Start action : click
10-05-2017 06:24:49 AM - [INFO]   - Finding Test Object with id 'Object Repository/core/open_module'
10-05-2017 06:24:49 AM - [END]    - End action : click
10-05-2017 06:24:49 AM - [ERROR]  - Test Cases/core/open_module_DASHBOARD FAILED because (of) java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.internal.WebUIAbstractKeyword
10-05-2017 06:24:49 AM - [END]    - End Test Case : Test Cases/core/open_module_DASHBOARD
10-05-2017 06:24:49 AM - [START]  - Start Test Case : Test Cases/core/open_module_ADDRESS_BOOK
10-05-2017 06:24:49 AM - [INFO]   - Evaluating variables for test case
10-05-2017 06:24:49 AM - [START]  - Start action : click
10-05-2017 06:24:49 AM - [INFO]   - Finding Test Object with id 'Object Repository/core/open_module'
10-05-2017 06:24:49 AM - [END]    - End action : click
10-05-2017 06:24:49 AM - [ERROR]  - Test Cases/core/open_module_ADDRESS_BOOK FAILED because (of) java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.internal.WebUIAbstractKeyword
10-05-2017 06:24:49 AM - [END]    - End Test Case : Test Cases/core/open_module_ADDRESS_BOOK
10-05-2017 06:24:49 AM - [START]  - Start Test Case : Test Cases/core/open_module_TRACKING
10-05-2017 06:24:49 AM - [INFO]   - Evaluating variables for test case
10-05-2017 06:24:49 AM - [START]  - Start action : click
10-05-2017 06:24:49 AM - [INFO]   - Finding Test Object with id 'Object Repository/core/open_module'
10-05-2017 06:24:49 AM - [END]    - End action : click
10-05-2017 06:24:49 AM - [ERROR]  - Test Cases/core/open_module_TRACKING FAILED because (of) java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.internal.WebUIAbstractKeyword
10-05-2017 06:24:49 AM - [END]    - End Test Case : Test Cases/core/open_module_TRACKING
10-05-2017 06:24:49 AM - [START]  - Start Test Case : Test Cases/core/open_module_TRANSPORT_ORDER
10-05-2017 06:24:49 AM - [INFO]   - Evaluating variables for test case
10-05-2017 06:24:49 AM - [START]  - Start action : click
10-05-2017 06:24:49 AM - [INFO]   - Finding Test Object with id 'Object Repository/core/open_module'
10-05-2017 06:24:49 AM - [END]    - End action : click
10-05-2017 06:24:49 AM - [ERROR]  - Test Cases/core/open_module_TRANSPORT_ORDER FAILED because (of) java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.internal.WebUIAbstractKeyword
10-05-2017 06:24:49 AM - [END]    - End Test Case : Test Cases/core/open_module_TRANSPORT_ORDER
10-05-2017 06:24:49 AM - [START]  - Start Test Case : Test Cases/core/open_module_REPORT
10-05-2017 06:24:50 AM - [INFO]   - Evaluating variables for test case
10-05-2017 06:24:50 AM - [START]  - Start action : click
10-05-2017 06:24:50 AM - [INFO]   - Finding Test Object with id 'Object Repository/core/open_module'
10-05-2017 06:24:50 AM - [END]    - End action : click
10-05-2017 06:24:50 AM - [ERROR]  - Test Cases/core/open_module_REPORT FAILED because (of) java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.internal.WebUIAbstractKeyword
10-05-2017 06:24:50 AM - [END]    - End Test Case : Test Cases/core/open_module_REPORT
10-05-2017 06:24:50 AM - [START]  - Start Test Case : Test Cases/core/open_module_PURCHASE_ORDER
10-05-2017 06:24:50 AM - [INFO]   - Evaluating variables for test case
10-05-2017 06:24:50 AM - [START]  - Start action : click
10-05-2017 06:24:50 AM - [INFO]   - Finding Test Object with id 'Object Repository/core/open_module'
10-05-2017 06:24:50 AM - [END]    - End action : click
10-05-2017 06:24:50 AM - [ERROR]  - Test Cases/core/open_module_PURCHASE_ORDER FAILED because (of) java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.internal.WebUIAbstractKeyword
10-05-2017 06:24:50 AM - [END]    - End Test Case : Test Cases/core/open_module_PURCHASE_ORDER
10-05-2017 06:24:50 AM - [START]  - Start Test Case : Test Cases/core/logout_spot2
10-05-2017 06:24:50 AM - [INFO]   - Evaluating variables for test case
10-05-2017 06:24:50 AM - [START]  - Start action : click
10-05-2017 06:24:50 AM - [INFO]   - Finding Test Object with id 'Object Repository/core/top_bar/top_bar_menu_by_icon'
10-05-2017 06:24:50 AM - [END]    - End action : click
10-05-2017 06:24:50 AM - [ERROR]  - Test Cases/core/logout_spot2 FAILED because (of) java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.internal.WebUIAbstractKeyword
10-05-2017 06:24:50 AM - [END]    - End Test Case : Test Cases/core/logout_spot2
10-05-2017 06:24:50 AM - [END]    - End Test Suite : WarmUp
Copying report to folder /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/katalon_test/workspace/spot-systemtest/src/katalon/spot/Reports...

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Test Suites/WarmUp - Headless - 20171005_062446........................8/8(100%)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to add additional configurations to your Jenkins as well.

1. Install this plugin: https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Xvfb+Plugin
2. After you've installed it, use this settings in 'Additional Settings' field of this plugin:

   export DISPLAY=:1.0

For your other issue, can you post the full test case script?